# CMake Debian vs Redhat/Arch-specific install directories

Tags: systemd, cmake

I have a systemd *.service file that I want to install using the CMake build system.

According to [Free Desktop policy](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) used by Debian these go in `/lib/systemd/system`.  In [Red Hat policy](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files) these go in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`.

Is there a CMake-native way to set this?

[GnuInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) understandably doesn't provide a path for systemd.

So far my solution is to:

```
option(USE_REDHAT_PATHS "Use Red Hat policy for install-paths" ON)

if ( ${USE_REDHAT_PATHS} )
  set( _SYSTEMD_DIR "/usr/lib/systemd/system" )
else()
  set( _SYSTEMD_DIR "/lib/systemd/system" )
endif()

install(FILES myservice.service DESTINATION ${_SYSTEMD_DIR})
```

It works, but requires user-side configuration. A `CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEMD` or `CMAKE_REDHAT` would be useful.

Using `ExecuteProcess` to call `uname -v` may help, but there are so many ways that it could break unless we support all possible upstream distributions too.

Comment: is `/lib -> usr/lib` a link on your RedHat systems? if so the Free Desktop path may also work there

Comment: I'm actually not using a RedHat system.  I'm porting a redhat application to debian and packaging it.  Therefore I don't have control over the user's environments.  Since it's being packaged, it's pretty important that I strictly adhere to the standards.

Comment: The document may have changed since you referenced it. As of this writing, `/usr/lib/systemd/system` appears in the [systemd.unit man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)